# EnumDisplayMonitors on specific video/graphics adapter?

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-monitors

I'm looking to enumerate all the displays attached to a specific video adapter. I'm successful in retrieving the video adapter info and creating a `HDC` from it, but when I call `EnumDisplayMonitors` on that `HDC`, nothing happens. `EnumDisplayMonitors` will work fine if I call it with `NULL` as the HDC.

**win32_root.cpp**

```
for (int i = 0;; ++i) {
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd = { 0 };
    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

    if (!EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &dd, 0)) {
        break;
    }

    if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE) {
        adapters.push_back(new Mage::Adapter(dd));
    }
}
```

**win32_display.cpp**

```
Mage::Adapter::Adapter(DISPLAY_DEVICE dd)
: device(dd)
{
    this->context = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", device.DeviceName, NULL, NULL);
    EnumDisplayMonitors(this->context, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)&(this->displays));
```

Which results in my callback function not being called at all. Changing `this->context` to `NULL` will enumerate all displays attached to my computer. Furthermore, this does properly enumerate the displays on the adapter, but I specifically need the display's `HMONITOR` struct:

```
if (!EnumDisplayDevices(device.DeviceName, i, &dm, 0)) {
    return;
}
```

How can I properly enumerate the displays/monitors on a specific `DISPLAY_DEVICE`?

Comment: Quote from the CreateDC() article: "If lpszDriver is DISPLAY or the device name of a specific display device, then lpszDevice must be NULL or that same device name."

Comment: @HansPassant I have already checked with the debugger, CreateDC() definitely returns a valid DC handle.

Comment: Why don't you just do it correctly and see what happens?

Comment: @HansPassant Following the `CreateDC()` article, I made the edits it suggested in the `lpszDriver` parameter, and it makes no difference. I get a valid DC handle one way or the other.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the hDC parameter in `EnumDisplayMonitors` is only there to let you find the monitors that a particular window is displayed on.

Answer (score 1):

EnumDisplayDevices is the call you want. You can ask it for adapters, or monitors attached to a specific adapter, etc - but you have to supply the right combination of info to get back a particular set of data.

From the ref link below:

To obtain information on a display monitor, first call EnumDisplayDevices with lpDevice set to NULL. Then call EnumDisplayDevices with lpDevice set to DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName from the first call to EnumDisplayDevices and with iDevNum set to zero. Then DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceString is the monitor name.

To query all monitor devices associated with an adapter, call EnumDisplayDevices in a loop with lpDevice set to the adapter name, iDevNum set to start at 0, and iDevNum set to increment until the function fails. Note that DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName changes with each call for monitor information, so you must save the adapter name. The function fails when there are no more monitors for the adapter.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa